# Selenium find all sub elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have html structure:

```
<div class="parent" data-index="0"><div class="sub">...</div></div>
<div class="parent" data-index="1"><div class="sub">...</div></div>
```

When I click on some parent element and all sub elements changes classes like so:

```
   <div class="parent selected" data-index="0"><div class="sub selected">...</div></div>
   <div class="parent" data-index="1"><div class="sub">...</div></div>
```

I want to loop over all parents and their sub elements with selenium no matter whether element is clicked or not
Right now I am doing this like so:

```
for i in range(n):
    parent= driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='parent' and @data-index='{i}']")
    for elem in parent.find_elements_by_xpath("./div"):
       do_something(elem)
```

However this doesn't catch parent elements which are clicked.

I also tried to change the xpath to `"//div[starts-with(@class,'parent') and @data-index='{i}']"` which catch also clicked parent elements.
But then `parent.find_elements_by_xpath("./div")` returns empty list

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am looking forward for any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find_by_class_name` like:

```py
for parent in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("parent"):
    for sub in parent.find_elements_by_class_name("sub"):
        do_something(sub)
```

Since both `class="parent selected"` and `class="parent"` are assigned to class `parent` that single query would select all parents (including selected ones)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this once:

```
parents = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'parent')]") # this xpath should highlight all the "div" tags which has "parent" in its class.
for parent in parents:
    elements = parent.find_elements_by_xpath("./div") # this should give all the child "div" tags. If they are nested use ".//div"
```